# Getting data in <tr> with thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

This is my code fragment:

```
<th:block th:each="d : ${items}">
    <!--<tr>-->
        <td th:text="${d.productname}"></td>
        <td th:text="${d.quantity}"></td>
        <td th:text="${d.price}"></td>
    <!--</tr>-->
</th:block>
```

`items` is an ArrayList.
I can get data if the `tr` doesn't exist (as you can see I commented it in the code).
If I put them back, my `th:text` gets `null` values.
I also tried tr `th:each` but it didn't help.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using thymeleaf-3.0.0 ,It worked for me.

```
    <table>
    <tr th:each="d : ${items}" >
                <td th:text="${d.productname}"></td>
                <td th:text="${d.quantity}"></td>
                <td th:text="${d.price}"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```